# Spring Assert NoClassDefFoundError when running Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, java-9

I am using Java 9, Maven and Spring boot 2.0.1 on Eclipse Oxygen.

When I run the application, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Assert
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:263)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.Assert
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Are you using maven? Check whether the missing class is present in your maven dependencies

Comment: I am using maven and the class is there.

Comment: Try using the latest version of jar

Comment: how are you running your Spring Boot application from Eclipse?

Comment: Right click on the project ->run as -> Spring boot app

Comment: perhaps open Run Configurations and check whether your Run is properly configured. I take you are using STS plugin. When in doubt, always try `mvn spring-boot:run` from the command line. Also check here for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Comment: Several levels of the tooling may contribute this, as on Java 9 you may need a non-trivial command line to get all you dependencies in the right combination of classpath and modulepath. One approach to analyse this would be by inspecting the command line created by Eclipse: after launching open the Debug View, select the second node and inspect its properties containing the full command line.

Comment: In case the problem is related to specifics of *test* dependencies, you may want to try a recent milestone build, please see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/M5/#jdt-test-sources - when trying, make sure you also have the latest m2e.

Comment: Thank you all, I updated my Java and maven to latest version.Everything working properly now.